# Cannot read response from udp multicast in python

Tags: python, sockets, udp, multicast, sonos

I can't seem to read the response that is sent back to me after
sending a multicast.  tcpdump shows that both the original multicast
and the response are sent.  Can someone suggest what is wrong with the
following python program?  My goal is to broadcast the discovery and
then read the response (which, as you can see from the tcpdump below)
is NOT sent back as a multicast, but is sent point to point back to
sending port.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP
from textwrap import dedent
from soco.utils import really_utf8

PLAYER_SEARCH = dedent("""\
    M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
    HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
    MAN: "ssdp:discover"
    MX: 1
    ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:ZonePlayer:1
    """).encode('utf-8')
MCAST_GRP = '239.255.255.250'
MCAST_PORT = 1900

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.sendto(really_utf8(PLAYER_SEARCH), (MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))
print(sock)

data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024, 0)     # hangs here forever
if data:
    print("Found Broadcast server at : ", addr)
    print(data)
```

The console output is as follows:

```
$ python simplesock.py
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=17, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 40690)>
```

The program hangs after printing the `sock` waiting for input.

This is the tcpdump that I get when I run the above program.  Notice
the server is responding to the port listed above in the console
output, so the server is definitely getting my original message.

```
21:27:36.864212 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 41099, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 147)
    ThinkPad-T480s.fios-router.home.40690 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 119
E.....@...&m...........l....M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
MAN: "ssdp:discover"
MX: 1
ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:ZonePlayer:1

21:27:37.361046 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25095, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 524)
    SonosZP.fios-router.home.34982 > ThinkPad-T480s.fios-router.home.40690: UDP, length 496
E...b.@.@.R...............Z.HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age = 1800
EXT:
LOCATION: http://192.168.1.195:1400/xml/device_description.xml
SERVER: Linux UPnP/1.0 Sonos/50.1-65071 (ZPS12)
ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:ZonePlayer:1
USN: uuid:RINCON_347E5CC2374C01400::urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:ZonePlayer:1
X-RINCON-HOUSEHOLD: Sonos_xxxUTzAZjabcDsaBadOOK2GQFP
X-RINCON-BOOTSEQ: 2
X-RINCON-WIFIMODE: 1
X-RINCON-VARIANT: 2
HOUSEHOLD.SMARTSPEAKER.AUDIO: Sonos_xxxUTzAZjabcDsaBadOOK2GQFP.RmcmkwBQ12BxWPa_fNdS
```

Python 3.6.7 running on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: Use `recv()` unless you want to capture the source-address, which you aren't. Is 0 really valid for that?

Comment: I do want to capture the source address.  Yes, 0 is valid for that.  And, using recv doesn't change the behavior - it still hangs waiting for a input.

Answer (score 0):

You're not joining the multicast group:

```
sock.setsockopt(
    socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
    socket.inet_aton(multicast_address) + socket.inet_aton(bind_address)
)
```

Here's a `listen_ssdp` method for asyncio: https://github.com/lbryio/aioupnp/blob/v0.0.14/aioupnp/protocols/ssdp.py#L121

The `SSDPProtocol` it uses successfully receives replies to SSDP/m-search requests like you're sending.

Also keep in mind routers are very finicky about the formatting of the m-search packet they will reply to, some in very stupid ways that deviate from the so called spec. If you consistently don't get replies from your code but do from something like a torrent client or `miniupnpc`, try capturing what the successful library sends so you can replicate it.